# How to extend a controller in ZF2?

Tags: controller, zend-framework2, extends

I want to extend all my controllers by different `ParentController`s specified for each module separately.

And I don't know, where to place the extended controller, and what to write in the top level controller.

I want to do something like that:

**`module/Application/src/Application/Controller/IndexController.php`**

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Application\Controller\ApplicationHeadController;

class IndexController extends ApplicationHeadController {

    public function indexAction() {

    }

}
```

**`module/Application/src/Application/ApplicationHeadController`**

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class ApplicationHeadController extends AbstractActionController {

    public function init() {
        parent::init();

        // some common code for every controller in this module
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Alex here: try not using overloading for this kind of task. Overloading (ie, using (abstract) classes and exstend them with your specific controller) creates difficulties at a later time.

For instance, what if one controller in the future should not execute that common code? You need to create logic to disable the execution of that common code with a flag in the constructor or something uglier. Or if you want to create a REST interface and one controller must extend the `AbstractRestfulController` instead of the `AbstractActionController`?

Zend Framework 2 provides hooks where you can do this kind of work much more flexible. A "listener" is such hook for an "event" triggered. A controller sends out several events where you can listen to in your module class. One of them is "dispatch", which is called when your `fooAction()` methods run.

```
namespace MyModule;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap($e)
    {
        $app = $e->getApplication();
        $em  = $app->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();

        $em->attach('MyModule', 'dispatch', function($e) {
            $controller = $e->getTarget();

            // Here your common code
        });
    }
}
```

You listen to the `dispatch` event inside the group of events from `MyModule`. You can read more [about the event manager](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.event-manager.event-manager.html) and [the module class](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.module-manager.module-class.html#the-mvc-bootstrap-event).

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated?

```
class A 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->doSomeFancyStuff();  
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->doMoreFancyStuffInChildClassOnly();
    }
}
```

And if you don't need to do `doMoreFancyStuffInChildClassOnly()` then you don't need to overwrite the function or even call `parent::__construct()` as it is automatically happening. Read yourself into the basics of [PHP5 OOP-Constructs](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.decon.php)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is better to use dispatch listeners in this case. You can also take a look at [Matthew's article](http://mwop.net/blog/2012-07-30-the-new-init.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using php 5.4, a trait might be what you are after. It has the simplicity of Sam's answer, without the possible problems that Jurian points out.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

(Note: traits have their weaknesses too, particularly if you start using a lot of them, but for the right job they can be the right tool)